# iptables: block all inbound traffic over a certain port number

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, firewall

It is possible using iptables (on Debian) to block all inbound connections for all the ports with a port number over (as an example) 16000.

Like this (using 16000 as reference):

The port 15999 is open for input, instead from port 16000 to 65535 inbound connections are dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ports are contiguous, like yours are, then use the

> --destination-port,--dport [!] port[:port]

[syntax](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) to set up the range:

```
... --destination-port 16000:65535 ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Multiport for that

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 16000:65535 -j DROP
```

also you may try

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  --dport 16000:65535 -j DROP
```

Comment: Multiport is only required if the ports are not contiguous

Comment: I tested the second command successfully. As Jeff says, now the ports are contiguous.

Comment: true :) it just to have whole picture, it is possible to do in both ways

Answer (score 2):

You have to block tcp and udp ports:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 16000:65535 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --match multiport --dports 16000:65535 -j DROP
```

Comment: quoting the manpage "Protocol all will match with all protocols and is taken as default when this option is omitted." (the OP didn't specify protocols)

Comment: The problem is that -p all makes impossible to use --dport.

From server fault:

http://serverfault.com/questions/279361/iptables-p-all-dport

Comment: I think `-p all`  has problem with --dport not `-p udp` or `-p tcp`

Comment: Yes, "-p all" doesn't makes the flag --dport available